# How to fix "ah00169: caught SIGTERM, shutting down" error?

Tags: ubuntu, webserver, apache2, vps, logfile

I am trying to setup my website on a web VPS, but there are still some errors which prevent it from working.

In the log files I found these errors:

> [Mon Jan 14 22:20:26.519775 2019] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 25164] AH00169: caught SIGTERM, shutting down

> [Mon Jan 14 22:20:26.620269 2019] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 25263] AH00163: Apache/2.4.29 (Ubuntu) configured -- resuming normal operations

> [Mon Jan 14 22:20:26.620320 2019] [core:notice] [pid 25263] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'

What do these errors mean and how do I solve them?

When I open my website it shows me this:

```
This page isn’t working
www.specialselektrods.lv is currently unable to handle this request.
HTTP ERROR 500
```

Comment: have you solve this error?\

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error, the problem was a cronjob that runs every night and ended apache. (certbot renew) you should check your cron jobs!

you can check your cronjobs via crontab -e